Incorrect numbered folder occasionally when exporting file
In this bit of code in a PowerShell script, it moves a file based off it's number inside the file name into the corresponding export folder with the correct number.
For for example in this instance it will move the file with 472 in the file name into the export folder named 472.
Unfortunately on occasion (seemingly random) it seems to be moving the 472 file into the 047 folder. I feel like it isn't a coincidence due to 47 existing in both.
Foreach ($file in $fileArray)
{
    $siteDir =  getSiteIDFromFileName($file);
    writeToLog "Site Dir: $sitedir";
    $eodFull = $eodBaseLocation + $siteDir + '/exports/';

Function below
function getSiteIDFromFileName
{
    Param ([string]$fileName)

    [int]$returnedInt = -1;
    $siteID = $file.name.Substring(4,3);
    [bool]$isNumber = [int32]::TryParse($siteID, [ref]$returnedInt)
    
    if($isNumber -AND ($returnedInt -gt 0))    
    {
        return '{0:d3}' -f $returnedInt;
    }
}

File Array
if ($env -eq 'Test')
    {
        $fileArray = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $exportLocation | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer -AND ($_.Name  -Match "MFILE") -AND ($_.Name  -NotMatch "transferred") -AND ($_.Name  -NotMatch "TEST")});
    }
    else
    {
        $fileArray = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $exportLocation | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer -AND ($_.Name  -Match "MFILE") -AND ($_.Name  -NotMatch "transferred")});
    }

The thing that bothers me most is that it is intermittent.

The culprit is, most probably, getSiteIDFromFileName(). Can you post the code of that function?

Looking at an older question of yours, you are probably clipping of a numeric ID from a file name like this $Site = $_.fullname.substring(18, 3). Because file FullNames can vary in length, this is probably the worst way of doing that. Please do what @sirtao commented and show us the full code of your function getSiteIDFromFileName(). Also show us how you obtain $fileArray and as sidenote, PowerShell is not C#, so you can omite the semi-colons at the end of each code line.

@Chris That'd suggest you have a file named xxxx472_MFILE or similar

The file name begins as MFILE472.datestring.txt but is converted to TEST.MFILE472.datestring.txt if the env is Test
It will insert this TEST. after it has received the SiteID
            if ($env -eq 'Test')
            {
                $timeStampedFileName = 'TEST.' + $timeStampedFileName;
                writeToLog "Test timestamped filename: $timeStampedFileName";
            }


Your getSiteIDFromFileName takes a parameter $filename but then references a variable $file in $file.name.Substring(4,3) which is presumably a variable you’re using in the calling scope. Try switching $file.name to $filename to use the parameter instead…

You can do without that function getSiteIDFromFileName completely and use a regex -replace instead (for details see below).
Also, you don't need ! $_.PSIsContainer if you append switch -File to the Get-ChildItem command, and you can speed things up by filtering for files that have 'MFILE' in their name.
Try below
# create a regex string for the -notmatch operator, depending if $env equals 'Test' or not
$excluded  = if ($env -eq 'Test') { 'transferred|test' } else { 'transferred' }

$fileArray = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $exportLocation -Filter '*MFILE*' -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch $excluded})
foreach ($file in $fileArray) {
    # get the three digits from the file name directly after 'MFILE'
    $siteDir =  $file.Name -replace '^.*MFILE(\d{3}).*', '$1'  
    # invoke your script to write the siteId to a log file
    writeToLog "Site Dir: $sitedir"
    # create the full target path to move the file to
    $eodFull = Join-Path -Path ('{0}{1}' -f $eodBaseLocation, $siteDir) -ChildPath 'exports'
    # if needed, create the target folder
    $null = New-Item -Path $eodFull -ItemType Directory -Force
    # move the file
    $file | Move-Item -Destination $eodFull
}

Regex details
^            Assert position at the beginning of the string
.            Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
MFILE        Match the characters “MFILE” literally
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d        Match a single digit 0..9
      {3}    Exactly 3 times
)           
.            Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

